# Can $f$ be not computable even if $L$ is decidable?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, undecidability

I am trying to teach myself computability theory with a textbook. According to my book, a function $f$ over an alphabet $A=\{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z\}$ is only computable iff the language

$$
L = \{s\#^j\sigma : s\in A^*, \sigma \in A, \text{ the }j\text{'th symbol of } f(s)\text{ is } \sigma\}$$

is decidable. Why is that? Couldn't a function $f$ be not computable even if $L$ is decidable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $L$ is decidable then you can use it's decider to compute $f$:
for the first symbol of $f(s)$ run the decider on the input $s\#x$ for any $x\in A$. For **one** of them, the decider will answer *YES*--this is the first letter in $f(s)$.

Continue doing this (e.g., for the second letter, decide if $s\#\#x \in L$, etc.), and reveal $f(s)$ letter-by-letter until the time where the decider answers *NO* for all $x\in A$, which means you reached the end of $f(s)$.

So if $L$ is decidable, $f$ is computable. Conversely, if $f$ is not computable, it can't be that $L$ is decidable.